# Is MDM a Storage?

Tags: database, mdm

I'm working on my college assignment. Where I need to study about databases. 
But while going through I came across a word `MDM`.

Read about alot but not able to imagine what is it actually.

Just want to confirm Is MDM a kind of data storage or It is utilized to connect with database to work on stored data in Database..?

Please help me to clear my doubt.

Comment: Can you give an example of the context where this acronym was used? The meaning I'm familiar with (Mobile Device Management) would probably not be relevant to a discussion of databases.

Comment: kindly provide some information in the question

Comment: @duskwuff, I was reading this https://profisee.com/master-data-management-what-why-how-who/ , after got to know about MDM word in my CS lab ...?